# Toggling class on form completion - Angular

Tags: angular

I have a form written in Angular.

The progress bar at the top runs from 1 - 4.

When a user is on step 1, the class is active and when the user completes step 1 and moves onto step 2, the class on step 1 changes to complete and step 2 gets the active class and so on.

I have written the following like this

```
<div
    id="Progress_Bar___Element___Compl"
    class="Progress_Bar___Element___Complete"
    [ngClass]="{ 'active' : currentSection === _stage.YourStatus, 'completed' : currentSection === _stage.AboutYou || _stage.Affordability || _stage.CreateAccount  }"
  >
    <div id="Your_status_A6_Text_22" class="progress-label">
      <span>Your status</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    id="Progress_Bar___Element___Compl_A6_Component_25"
    class="Progress_Bar___Element___Complete"
    [ngClass]="{ active: currentSection == _stage.AboutYou, 'completed' : currentSection === _stage.Affordability }"
  >
    <div id="About_you" class="progress-label">
      <span>About you</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    id="Progress_Bar___Element___Compl_A6_Component_26"
    class="Progress_Bar___Element___Complete"
    [ngClass]="{ active: currentSection == _stage.Affordability }"
  >
    <div id="Affordability" class="progress-label">
      <span>Affordability</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    id="Progress_Bar___Element___Compl_A6_Component_27"
    class="Progress_Bar___Element___Complete"
    [ngClass]="{ active: currentSection == _stage.CreateAccount }"
  >
    <div id="Create_account" class="progress-label">
      <span>Create account</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code works fine, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to write this? If not, great but if there is, that would be even better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is _stage an enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Angular material Stepper component?

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Because Angular Material comes out of box from Angular and this Stepper component already has UI function that has similar logic that you wrote, which means you do not have to duplicate same logic in your repository.